# AppCompat 23.2 use VectorDrawableCompat with RemoteViews (AppWidget) on API<21

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, remoteview, android-vectordrawable

I have an AppWidget and I'd like to use VectorDrawables in it also on pre-Lollipop devices.
VectorDrawableCompat won't work with the RemoteViews I create.

To keep my app APK size down, I don't want to add alternative PNG versions of my drawables for older API platforms.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**UPDATE 22/10/2017**

As noted by @user924 now *AppCompatDrawableManager* access is restricted to its own library.
*ContextCompat.getDrawable(...)* should do the trick.

**UPDATE 05/09/2016**

As noted by @kirill-kulakov in its answer, the latest updates of the Support Library restricted the TintContextWrapper visibility to its own package.
I'm updating my answer to remove the incorrect code, but please thank Kirill for the correction!

## VectorDrawable and RemoteViews pre-Lollipop

You can avoid adding alternative rasterized versions of your vector drawable resources <strike>with an easy **hack**: use AppCompat *TintResources* through *TintContextWrapper*</strike> <strike>using *AppCompatDrawableManager*</strike> using *ContextCompat*.

<strike>*TintResources*</strike> <strike>*AppCompatDrawableManager*</strike> *ContextCompat* is the class that among other things, on pre-Lollipop devices, parses the *VectorDrawable*s XML files and convert them into *VectorDrawableCompat* instances that can be used all the way down to API 7.

Then, once you have a *VectorDrawableCompat* instance, rasterize it onto a Bitmap. You'll later use this bitmap in a remote *ImageView*.

### Before we begin: AppCompat Library

Ensure you are using Android Studio 2.0+ and have configured your app **`build.gradle`** file as follows:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

### Update your AppWidgetProvider

First of all: don't set your vector drawable resources inside your *RemoteViews* layout file (neither `android:src` nor `app:srcCompat` will work). You'll have to set them programmatically.

Inside your *AppWidgetProvider* class set the vector resource or a rasterized version depending on the API level:

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget_layout);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView, R.drawable.vector);

} else {
  Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.vector);
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                 d.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                                 Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
  d.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
  d.draw(c);
  remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, b);
}
```

### References

- ContextCompat [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/compat/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java#L349)
- Chris Banes' [AppCompat v23.2 - Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.f1ynl4cwk) blog post introduces *VectorDrawableCompat* and explains the hack that AppCompat uses to make them work on pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: TintContextWrapper is not public in android.support.v7.widget; cannot be accessed from outside package

Comment: error on `Bitmap.createBitmap(d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                 d.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                                 Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710994/vectordrawable-to-bitmap-bitmap-sethasalphaboolean-on-a-null-object-referenc

Comment: `AppCompatDrawableManager can only be called from within the same library group`

Comment: Hi @user924, I updated the answer to add compatibility to the latest Android Support Library versions! Thank you!

Comment: `As noted by @user924 now AppCompatDrawableManager access is restricted to its own library.` a) That doesn't prevent you from actually using it. b) There's now public API in `AppCompatResources.getDrawable(...)`.

Comment: also `setImageViewResource` mb will work for < 21 if add `AppCompatImageView` (instead of ImageView) to layout

Comment: @user924,RemoteViews surely doesn't work with AppCompatImageView. The list of widgets and layout you can use in RemoteViews is defined in it's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html)

Answer (score 8):

The following method will convert the `vector drawable` to  a bitmap before, this should do the trick.

```
public static BitmapDrawable vectorToBitmapDrawable(Context ctx, @DrawableRes int resVector) {
    return new BitmapDrawable(ctx.getResources(), vectorToBitmap(ctx, resVector));
}

public static Bitmap vectorToBitmap(Context ctx, @DrawableRes int resVector) {
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(ctx, resVector);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```