# App not running on Hardware Device in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to Android Development so I am facing an error in running app on hardware device.

My android device is connected properly to Android Studio.It runs normally,shows in the Android monitor but the app isn't responding on the device unlike the emulator. I am using Samsung Galaxy S3.

Note: the emulator works on API 24 so there's no API problem. I also write `android:debugger="true"` in AndroidManifest.

The Program is about Shared Preferences. There is no problem in the code it works completely fine in emulator.

> The error might be in build or any other configuration because even if i install apk it isn't responding

Logcat:

```
> 08-26 08:17:27.776 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26
> 08:17:47.785 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26
> 08:22:08.725 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26
> 08:22:28.745 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26
> 08:24:09.330 5459-5474/? E/SAMMLibraryCore: Not AMS File(Not enough
> data size) 08-26 08:24:09.330 5459-5474/? E/Qdio::ParseQdio: File
> Search Error 08-26 08:26:49.815 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 08:27:09.825 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 08:27:30.045 3001-3069/? E/PlayCommon: [91]
> com.google.android.play.a.l.a(938): Failed to connect to server:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
> "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname 08-26
> 08:27:31.615 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bcbfa8 08-26 08:27:31.615 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@427d4d40 08-26 08:27:31.630 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42c7e928 08-26 08:27:31.655 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42c7ec08 08-26 08:27:31.680 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42c7eee8 08-26 08:27:31.685 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42cab370 08-26 08:27:31.700 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42cab650 08-26 08:27:31.720 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42cab930 08-26 08:27:31.790 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42cabac0 08-26 08:27:31.835 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bbf0f0 08-26 08:27:31.885 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bbf398 08-26 08:27:31.890 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bbf678 08-26 08:27:31.900 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bbf808 08-26 08:27:31.935 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4263b8e8 08-26 08:27:31.940 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4263bbc8 08-26 08:31:32.780 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:31:52.795 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:32:12.845 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:33:31.265 5975-5975/?
> E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no
> sepolicy file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:31.265 5975-5975/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1],
> There is no sepolicy version file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:31.265 5975-5975/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority ,
> loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9300_4.3_0016
>                                            
>                                             08-26 08:33:31.265 5975-5975/? E/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:
> seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts 08-26 08:33:32.290
> 5994-5994/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0],
> There is no sepolicy file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:32.290 5994-5994/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1],
> There is no sepolicy version file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:32.290 5994-5994/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority ,
> loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9300_4.3_0016
>                                            
>                                             08-26 08:33:32.290 5994-5994/? E/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:
> seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts 08-26 08:33:33.065
> 6007-6007/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0],
> There is no sepolicy file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:33.065 6007-6007/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1],
> There is no sepolicy version file 
>                                             08-26 08:33:33.065 6007-6007/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority ,
> loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9300_4.3_0016
>                                            
>                                             08-26 08:33:33.065 6007-6007/? E/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:
> seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts 08-26 08:36:14.840
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:36:34.860
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:36:54.875
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:41:16.680
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:41:36.685
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:45:57.645
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:46:17.750
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:50:38.580
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:50:58.645
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:55:19.905
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 08:55:40.565
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:00:02.595
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:00:22.630
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:00:42.725
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:01:46.060
> 3001-3069/? E/PlayCommon: [91] com.google.android.play.a.l.a(938):
> Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to
> resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with
> hostname 08-26 09:01:48.195 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred
> sending report com.crashlytics.android.Z@428b7528 08-26 09:01:48.195
> 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429254f0 08-26 09:01:48.210 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42925940 08-26 09:01:48.225 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42928958 08-26 09:01:48.230 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42928d80 08-26 09:01:48.245 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42928f70 08-26 09:01:48.250 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292ade0 08-26 09:01:48.265 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292af40 08-26 09:01:48.285 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292b208 08-26 09:01:48.290 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292c350 08-26 09:01:48.295 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@428989d8 08-26 09:01:48.325 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42898060 08-26 09:01:48.325 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42895cf0 08-26 09:01:48.340 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4288fde0 08-26 09:01:48.360 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4288e850 08-26 09:05:03.865 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:05:23.885 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:09:44.680 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:10:04.725 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:14:25.925 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:14:45.925 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:19:07.830 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:19:27.830 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:23:48.010 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:24:08.010 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:24:28.035 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:28:29.640 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:28:49.690 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:29:09.910 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:29:50.265 6164-6164/?
> E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no
> sepolicy file 
>                                             08-26 09:29:50.265 6164-6164/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [1],
> There is no sepolicy version file 
>                                             08-26 09:29:50.265 6164-6164/? E/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority ,
> loading version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9300_4.3_0016
>                                            
>                                             08-26 09:29:50.265 6164-6164/? E/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:
> seapp_contexts file is loaded from /seapp_contexts 08-26 09:30:09.720
> 2796-2808/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() ->
> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: mobilepersonalfeeds
> 08-26 09:30:09.980 2796-2808/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl]
> getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: mobilepersonalfeeds
> 08-26 09:30:10.165 2796-4127/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl]
> getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: mobilepersonalfeeds
> 08-26 09:30:10.415 2796-2808/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl]
> getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: mobilepersonalfeeds
> 08-26 09:30:14.645 2796-2807/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl]
> getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service: mobilepersonalfeeds
> 08-26 09:30:14.950 2796-2808/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl]
> getToken() -> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service:
> oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow 08-26 09:30:15.040
> 2796-2807/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() ->
> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service:
> oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow 08-26 09:30:15.120
> 2796-5902/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() ->
> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service:
> oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow 08-26 09:30:15.275
> 2796-4127/? E/Auth: [GoogleAccountDataServiceImpl] getToken() ->
> NETWORK_ERROR. Account: <ELLIDED:639870576>, App:
> com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox, Service:
> oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googlenow 08-26 09:33:30.960
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:33:50.890
> 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:37:58.755
> 3001-3069/? E/PlayCommon: [91] com.google.android.play.a.l.a(938):
> Failed to connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to
> resolve host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with
> hostname 08-26 09:38:01.250 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred
> sending report com.crashlytics.android.Z@42816028 08-26 09:38:01.250
> 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4281f318 08-26 09:38:01.260 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@428210c0 08-26 09:38:01.280 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42821370 08-26 09:38:01.285 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42821620 08-26 09:38:01.335 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42821890 08-26 09:38:01.340 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42813368 08-26 09:38:01.365 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42813200 08-26 09:38:01.370 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42811f30 08-26 09:38:01.375 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42811ca0 08-26 09:38:01.390 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42811b38 08-26 09:38:01.405 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@428118b0 08-26 09:38:01.415 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42811620 08-26 09:38:01.430 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@428114b8 08-26 09:38:01.465 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@428111a8 08-26 09:38:14.705 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:38:34.715 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:42:56.860 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:43:16.870 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:47:38.685 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:47:58.685 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:52:19.695 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:52:39.705 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:52:59.725 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 09:56:12.020 1940-1989/?
> E/SecTVOutService: virtual void
> android::SecTVOutService::setHdmiStatus(uint32_t)::mSecHdmi.connect()
> fail 08-26 09:56:12.025 2344-2483/? E/SEC PowerHAL: sysfs_write :
> Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such file or
> directory 08-26 09:56:12.025 2344-2483/? E/SEC PowerHAL: sysfs_write :
> Error opening /sys/class/input/input8/enabled: No such file or
> directory 08-26 09:56:12.030 2821-2821/? E/NfcService: callback ==
> null 08-26 09:56:21.615 2344-2469/? E/KeyguardViewMediator:
> resetStateLocked 08-26 09:56:21.660 2344-2483/? E/SEC PowerHAL:
> sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input1/enabled: No such
> file or directory 08-26 09:56:21.660 2344-2483/? E/SEC PowerHAL:
> sysfs_write : Error opening /sys/class/input/input8/enabled: No such
> file or directory 08-26 09:56:21.695 2344-2470/? E/KeyguardHostView:
> KeyguardHostView() 08-26 09:56:21.815 2821-2821/? E/NfcService:
> callback == null 08-26 09:56:22.010 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.015 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.015 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.015 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.080 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.080 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.080 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.080 2344-2470/? E/LSO: LSO Service is
> not yet ready!!! 08-26 09:56:22.270 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 09:56:42.580 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 09:57:02.585 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 09:57:22.620 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 09:57:42.660 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:02:03.025 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:02:23.035 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:06:44.615 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:07:05.020 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:11:26.070 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:11:46.125 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query:
> requestFailed 08-26 10:13:51.725 3001-3069/? E/PlayCommon: [91]
> com.google.android.play.a.l.a(938): Failed to connect to server:
> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
> "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname 08-26
> 10:14:26.595 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42bb59d8 08-26 10:14:26.610 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42a26250 08-26 10:14:26.625 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429cfee8 08-26 10:14:26.650 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429998c8 08-26 10:14:26.655 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4298f150 08-26 10:14:26.665 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4294e4f0 08-26 10:14:26.675 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429406b8 08-26 10:14:26.690 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42939520 08-26 10:14:26.710 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42936b68 08-26 10:14:26.725 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42934ee0 08-26 10:14:26.730 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429330d8 08-26 10:14:26.740 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429327f8 08-26 10:14:26.755 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292c3e0 08-26 10:14:26.770 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4292b158 08-26 10:14:26.775 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42928ec0 08-26 10:16:07.830 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:16:27.835 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:20:48.595 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:21:08.665 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:21:28.690 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:25:31.335 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:25:51.720 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:26:11.910 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:30:32.720 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:30:52.745 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:35:12.930 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:35:32.945 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:39:55.040 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:40:15.035 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:44:36.580 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:44:56.595 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:49:17.691 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:49:37.710 2764-2923/?
> E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26 10:49:51.735 3001-3069/?
> E/PlayCommon: [91] com.google.android.play.a.l.a(938): Failed to
> connect to server: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve
> host "play.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname 08-26
> 10:49:57.730 2764-2923/? E/GlsClient-query: requestFailed 08-26
> 10:50:17.750 5140-5179/? E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@425c6e88 08-26 10:50:17.765 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42920948 08-26 10:50:17.775 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@429206a0 08-26 10:50:17.780 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@42920308 08-26 10:50:17.795 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291f9f8 08-26 10:50:17.810 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291f648 08-26 10:50:17.820 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291f3d8 08-26 10:50:17.825 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291ee48 08-26 10:50:17.850 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291eaa8 08-26 10:50:17.870 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291e650 08-26 10:50:17.885 5140-5179/?
> E/Crashlytics: Error occurred sending report
> com.crashlytics.android.Z@4291e2a8 08-26 10:50:17.900 5140-5179/?
```

Logcat problem which i saw right now(28-08-2016) might be of help

> 08-28 17:05:15.268 14621-14621/com.iamcool.sharedpref
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.iamcool.sharedpref/com.iamcool.sharedpref.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an
>   incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for
>   VectorDrawableCompat.
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built
>   with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for
>   VectorDrawableCompat.
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
>                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
>                                                                               at com.iamcool.sharedpref.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168) 
>                                                                               at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225) 
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041) 
>                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please check the logcat report in android monitor. If you are getting error post the logcat report in the quesiton

Comment: Have you enabled usb debugging in the developer options?

Comment: You need to provide a bit of context regarding your app (a couple of activities doing n/w call, db read/white, etc) and the issue (immediate hang-up, hangup after a certain click, etc)

Comment: I have enabled usb debugging.The code works completely fine with emulator.

Comment: Seems that your application does not deal correctly with a situation when there is no working network connection on the device

Comment: @StenSoft I tried on another samsung device which had a working connection but same problem pops up.its not responding

Comment: your exception is this `This app has been built with an incorrect configuration. Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat`, have you looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143867/why-this-app-has-been-built-with-an-incorrect-configuration-error-occured-in-s OR here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633410/appcompat-23-2-use-vectordrawablecompat-with-remoteviews-appwidget-on-api21