# VectorDrawable to Bitmap: Bitmap.setHasAlpha(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to get `Bitmap` from `VectorDrawable` (xml image):

```
VectorDrawable vectorDrawable = (VectorDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.test);

Bitmap bitmap = UtilMethods.getBitmapFromVector(vectorDrawable);
```

But app crashes on `Bitmap.createBitmap` method with `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Bitmap.setHasAlpha(boolean)' on a null object reference` error

```
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromVector(VectorDrawable vectorDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

p.s.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```

here some simple xml drawable (comma symbol)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="16000dp"
    android:height="16000dp"
    android:viewportWidth="16000"
    android:viewportHeight="16000">


    <path
        android:fillColor="#040607"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M3637 11910 l486 -730 484 0 c265 0 483 3 483 8 0 4 -130 331 -288 727 l-288 720
-682 3 -682 2 487 -730z" />

</vector>
```

I tried every method from [Getting Bitmap from vector drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33696488/getting-bitmap-from-vector-drawable/35347960)
All of them fails on this `.createBitmap` method

seems to be

```
android:width="16000dp"
android:height="16000dp"
android:viewportWidth="16000"
android:viewportHeight="16000">
```

are to big values...

I've added not full xml, there are more `path` tags, so it's not just comma symbol with such big values:)

I tried to reduce values to 2000 (e.g.) and app stopped crashing, but it ruined my image

I made vector drawable from svg using http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Comment: When you say it ruined your image, in what way is it ruined? remember that to change the size, only change the width and height attributes, leave the viewportWidth and viewportHeight as they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
android:width="16000dp"
android:height="16000dp"
```

to

```
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
```

don't need to chagne:

```
android:viewportWidth="16000"
android:viewportHeight="16000">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate a 16000x16000dp Bitmap that, based on the density of the display you're running your app, must be multiplied by a factor of 2 for xhdpi, 3 for xxhdpi and 4 for xxxhdpi.
This causes memory problems since you are trying to allocate a Bitmap that is larger than 1000MB.

You need to scale down your Drawable. It shouldn't cause the quality loss you're experiencing so I suggest you to check your SVG or the output of svg2android for errors...

Also remember that you can't put Bitmap larger or higher than GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE into ImageView.
See: ["Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271020/bitmap-too-large-to-be-uploaded-into-a-texture)