# RemoteViews: When using VectorDrawableCompat, you need to use app:srcCompat

Tags: android

> When using VectorDrawableCompat, you need to use app:srcCompat

But for `RemoveViews` (for custom notifications) it only works with `android:src`

```
new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), layout);
```

with `app:srcCompat` `ImageViews` are invisible

Comment: That's because `srcCompat` is an attribute of `AppCompatImageView`. `RemoteViews` do not use `AppCompatImageView`s. For versions before Lollipop, you'll have to either create separate images and layouts for those versions, or convert and set the drawable programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35633411.

Comment: @MikeM. with that solution I get another error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633410/appcompat-23-2-use-vectordrawablecompat-with-remoteviews-appwidget-on-api21/35633411#comment80637561_35633411

Comment: @MikeM. seems a bug, added annotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44926919/7767664

Comment: Ah, yep, looks like they restricted that class relatively recently.