# Resource not found exception for vectordrawables

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-parsing, android-gradle-plugin

I am using vector drawables programmatically instead of png like :

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_navigate_before_black_24dp));
```

Everything is working fine but the app crashes in android 4.2 & below. Am getting the following log

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2842)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:1521)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5326)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate    (Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity  (ActivityThread.java:2218)
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: 
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner (Drawable.java:917)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml (Drawable.java:858)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable (Resources.java:2839)
```

I am using gradle 3.0.1 and also added

`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`

still no help.

Comment: might be the grammar.

Comment: I'l work on it.

Comment: Please take a look at the accepted answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633410/appcompat-23-2-use-vectordrawablecompat-with-remoteviews-appwidget-on-api21

Comment: you have to correct your vector drawable path, if drawable is showing in drawable folder, then clean your project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Check vector drawable `<path>`. Sometimes this happens when `<path>` tag in XML file is too long.
2. Try to move your image from `drawable` to `drawable-nodpi`.

**UPDATE**

3. Try to use AppCompatResources.getDrawable(view.getContext(), id); when getting drawable

Comment: I am using vectordrawables downloaded from official google material design site. Also the app is working fine in maximum devices except for few like Samsung galaxy s duos, Xiaomi note 2 etc

Comment: there are just two folders in my res folder 1. drawable 2.drawable-24

Comment: @asishrauto so create another folder

Comment: sure @AntonKazakov

Comment: Your update worked fine on Android 5, thank you.