# How exactly VectorDrawables can be used in Android Widgets on Pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, vector, widget, android-widget, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to use vector drawable in my **widget** bt on pre-lollipop, the image not displays, as I tried displaying image programmatically bcoz **app:srcCompat** don't work in case of widgets, based on the answers given in the following:

[AppCompat 23.2 use VectorDrawableCompat with RemoteViews (AppWidget) on API<21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633410/appcompat-23-2-use-vectordrawablecompat-with-remoteviews-appwidget-on-api21)

but after using the above approach I end up with this stack trace:

```
02-11 18:55:12.686 12176-12176/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.android.mygarden, PID: 12176
                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.example.android.mygarden.PlantWidgetProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/water_drop_blue.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08008d
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2580)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/water_drop_blue.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f08008d
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
                                                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:353)
                                                   at com.example.android.mygarden.PlantWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(PlantWidgetProvider.java:49)
                                                   at com.example.android.mygarden.PlantWidgetProvider.onUpdate(PlantWidgetProvider.java:76)
                                                   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                                                   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2148)
                                                   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710) 
                                                   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:353) 
                                                   at com.example.android.mygarden.PlantWidgetProvider.updateAppWidget(PlantWidgetProvider.java:49) 
                                                   at com.example.android.mygarden.PlantWidgetProvider.onUpdate(PlantWidgetProvider.java:76) 
                                                   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2573) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I do have my VectorDrawable in **drawable/water_drop_blue.xml**, bt it shows however **Resources$NotFoundException**.
Here is my **updateAppWidget** method:

```
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int appWidgetId) {

    // Create an Intent to launch MainActivity when clicked
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
        .getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.plant_widget);

    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_water_button, R.drawable.water_drop_blue);
    } else {
        Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.water_drop_blue);
        drawable = (DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)).mutate();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(c);
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_water_button, bitmap);
    }
```

My app widget layout file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_water_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/widget_plant_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/grass" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I have also included in app level build.gradle file

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

Please help me in displaying Vector in widget on pre-lollipop devices. I also tried using **AppCompatImageView** bt it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

in my project it's something like this:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_control, VectorUtil
                        .vectorToBitmap(context, R.drawable.chevron_left));
```

VectorUtils:

```
public static Bitmap vectorToBitmap(Context context, @DrawableRes int resVector) {
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(ctx, resVector);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

And it works fine.

But as i can see in your stacktrace it's problem with your vector, because of Tag that Parser of vector can't read it. Validate your vector.